# Selecting text in div on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I select text when I mouse over a div?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean selecting the text as if you dragged over it, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse). Whichever approach you try, to make it happen on mouseover, use [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/):

```
$('#mydiv').mouseenter( function(){
  my_superduper_selection_function(this);
});
```